# Can i rely over the "SSL on Shared Hosting"?

Tags: ssl, hosting, https, shared-hosting

My site will be using the APIs like Paypal and also making Facebook Apps. So lets say for Facebook, they allow only **https** for Apps to work with them. Mine is only hosted on **http** site.

- So can i solve this problem by buying a **Shared Hosting** with **SSL** included?

Is it a solution? or do i need to buy my own Certificate?

I'm not having enough knowledge about SSLs. Any suggestion please.

Answer (score 1):

Shared hosting means your web site will be located on the same machine as other customer's. It has repercussions with performances (you'0re sharing them with other apps) and security (a flaw in someone else web server can affect your own).

"SSL included" probably refers to having a SSL certificate issued to your host name by your hosting provider and installed in your (virtual) web root. That will secure the communication between your clients and your server.

So the two aren't directly linked and being on shared hosting shouldn't have any impact on your decision to purchase your own certificate or use the included one.

Personally, I wouldn't use shared hosting for a commercial web site, however.

Comment: At least, will it work or not? (by using Shared Hosting with SSL enabled)

Comment: Let me put it that way: it is possible to have SSL on a system that hosts several web site. There are technical requirements to make this work but it's possible. Whether it will work in the specific hosting provider you want to use, I cannot tell you since since you provided no specific details.

Comment: The details is: Actually, the first priority is to publish my FB Apps. I don't want to use the third-party SSL providers like, fbssl.co. So..?

Comment: I don't know what to tell you, really: I get the feeling that you do not understand how certificates works in relation with SSL and that this is confusing the issue for you. Perhaps you should research the matter a bit and ask more specific question.

Comment: LoL.. I have already mentioned `I'm not having enough knowledge about SSLs. Any suggestion please.` This mean "yes" i am not understand it. I just need to know a final answer whether i can use `Shared Hosting coming with SSL` or NOT (for FB Apps publishings). If i cant', i just need what to do. Buy what. Thats simply all :T

Answer (score 0):

In theory that could be a solution, but especially for things like Paypal I would recommend you get your own certificate.

Of course, you need a hosting solution which supports that since you will need your own IP to use with SSL.